# Using the decorator pattern on this composition

Tags: java, decorator, composition

Well I have a composition pattern used, where one graphic object is extended in a group and in rectangles. A group can have many rectangles and a paint() method call for the groups, calls paint methods in rectangles and each rectangle draws itself.

Now I need to somehow use a decorator pattern on that, to align the rectangles to the left or right side. Now If I use the decorator on the group, it just aligns the groups coordinates I guess, but since all the rectangles draw themselves, it doesn't have effect on them.

So any ideas how I could use the decorator pattern in here?

I mean the only way I can think of using it is to use the decorator wrapper around every rectangle and every element in the group that needs to be aligned. But doesn't this go against the policies of the decorator pattern? I mean the group technically doesn't know what it has in it's list, to it the elemnts are just GraphicObject instances and the rectangles don't know they are wrapped around with a decorator that would modify their coordinates before calling the rectangles' paint() methods.

If that's the only way, then how do I use it to decorate those items? Do I have to use reflections here or is there any other/more correct way to do that?

Some code:

```
if (mainGroup == null) {
        mainGroup = new Group();

        // first line
        currentBounds = convertToBoundsForLine(x, y, width, lineHeight, 1);
        //System.out.format("current bounds: x1=%d, y1=%d, x2=%d, y2=%d%n", currentBounds.getX(), currentBounds.getY(), currentBounds.getX2(), currentBounds.getY2());
        GraphicObject rect1 = new Rectangle(currentBounds);
        mainGroup.addChild(rect1);

        // other lines...

        // fifth line
        currentBounds = convertToBoundsForLine(x, y, width, lineHeight, 5);
        //System.out.format("current bounds: x1=%d, y1=%d, x2=%d, y2=%d%n", currentBounds.getX1(), currentBounds.getY1(), currentBounds.getX2(), currentBounds.getY2());
        GraphicObject rect5 = new Rectangle(currentBounds);

        // this is with the decorator wrapper around - should I use reflection here?
        GraphicObject blabla = new DecoratorLeft(rect5);
        mainGroup.addChild(blabla);
```

Well at the fifth line, you can see where I'm putting the rectangle inside the decorator before adding it to the group, so should I use reflections and use them on every rectangle which is added to the group. Or is there a better way to do that?

Or is the way I'm using the decorator here totally wrong in general?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here's how my paint method is implemented in the group:

```
public void draw(Graphics g, AlignStrategy align) {
    for (GraphicObject graphic: children) {
        graphic.draw(g, align);
    }
}
```

The group just calls the childrens draw methods.

The thing is, the decorator should be Universal in my opinon, according to the suggestion you gave it seems like it would make it dependant? I mean the group is the basically dependant on the alignment? What if say I created a decorator that would rotate the object, or switch coordinates x with y? I mean it's not about aligning left, right or center, it's about the decorator working without having to adapt the code too much to the decorator?

Comment: Could you explain how the drawing process works? I have an idea of how the group of rectangles gets built, but without knowing how painting works, I don't know how a painting decorator fits into this.

Comment: well. the group jus calls paint in all of the rectangles it has. and each of the rectangles has its own coordinates and according to them the paint methods paints the rectangle to the graphics g variable which comes as a parameter from the group in which it is. so basically my decorator would wrap the rectangle. the group calls the  the decorator which changes the coordinates for the rectangle to be  aligned to a side. then the decorator calls the paint method on the rectangle it wraps and it draws aligned. then the decorator returns the previous coordinates to the rectangle

Comment: @Dynguss forgot to add tag, see my comment above

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. I'll write up a quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have full control over the code behind `GraphicObject`, `Group`, `Rectangle`, and the like (i.e., if it's all your code), then I think using the decorator pattern may be the hard way to go. It would be simpler to implement the drawing alignment using code similar to AWT's `Layout` approach, where the parent object (probably a `Group` in your case) is given a single `Layout` object that is responsible for managing the arrangement of the parent's children. The default layout doesn't affect the children. The "align left" and "align right" layouts would make the necessary position changes to the children during a layout phase that takes place some time before painting. So `Group` would have a default `Layout` object that could be replaced by the alignment-specific versions when you need them.

If you don't have control of the code behind the drawing objects, then I think a decorator around `Group` would work better than decorating all the children. Have the `Group`-level decorator's `paint()` method manage the alignment of the children when it's called. This way you have only one decorator per `Group` rather than one decorator per drawable object. This is essentially the layout code rolled into a decorator class, but you could always break out the layout code and have the decorator call it.

Edit: Here's an example of the second case. To keep it simple, I only list the necessary parts, not the details.

```
public class GroupDecorator extends GraphicObject { //or extends whatever is best
    public GroupDecorator(Group wrappedGroup) { 
        myGroup = wrappedGroup;
    }

    public void paint() { //Assume this is your common paint() method
        //note I'm making up the names here, since I don't know them
        List groupsChildren = myGroup.getChildren(); 

        //The type of alignment is stored somewhere in this object
        //or is hard-coded. That's up to you. I'll assume it's stored somewhere...

        if (isAlignedLeft()) { 
          //align all the children to the left here
        } else if (isAlignedRight()){
          //align all the children to the right here
        } else { 
          //do nothing because no alignment is necessary
        }

        //call the wrapped Group's paint now. It will call its children's paint()s.
        myGroup.paint();

        //Unalign all the children here, if necessary, to put them back in 
        //their original state. How you implement that is up to you.
    }

}
// Somewhere in your main code...

    mainGroup = new Group();

    //Decorate mainGroup now...
    GroupDecorator decoratedGroup = new GroupDecorator(mainGroup);
    //Configure decoratedGroup to align however you want.

    // first line
    GraphicObject rect1 = new Rectangle();
    mainGroup.addChild(rect1);

    // other lines...

    // fifth line
    GraphicObject rect5 = new Rectangle();


    //Now use decoratedGroup now in place of mainGroup.
```

Comment: Well the thing is, the requirement is to use the decorator pattern in this case. And yeah, I do have the full control over the code. 
The thing with wrapping the decorator around the group is that the group object is aligned, but the rectangles inside it - aren't. If I modified the group, then it would probably go against the policy of the decorator pattern maybe? Because the Group would be modified? Hmm, maybe I lack fantasy here, could you give me an example how you imagine that?

Comment: @ArturasM I added an example to help explain the second approach.

Comment: well I'm not sure whether I've understood your example correctly. But yeah, thanks, I edited my post first, but now I'm reading your post again and thinking maybe I did understand it wrong, I'll try it maybe, hmm. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, but then it's like reimplementing the group as a form of decorator and instead of letting the group do the work the decorator actually takes all the work from the group and does it itself? So that's like inheritance, like overriding or reimplementing another class rather than the decorator? Isn't it? I mean technically we don't even need the wrapped group, we could just use this class instead of the group?

Comment: @ArturasM "like overriding or reimplementing another class..." Using a decorator is *like* those things, but it isn't *actually* those things. The purpose of a decorator is to add or otherwise modify one part of the inner object's functionality (in this case alignment). Different decorators would be used to modify other behavior. "we could just use this class instead of the group" No, because the decorator knows nothing about drawing, only alignment changes. It defers drawing to the `Group` object `myGroup` itself.

Comment: @ArturasM A decorator has to *look* like the thing it's decorating, but it will defer most of the actual calls to that wrapped object. That's what makes it a decoration. In this case, the decoration is "alignment changes," and all the rest is handled by the decorated (wrapped) object.

Comment: Yeah, I see, you might be right about all this, it might be the correct/best way to do it, I'm still looking at your code. It's kind of slow, cause it's late here. Yeah that might be the best way I think, I just would need to modify it, maybe put every children of the group to another wrapper, because a group may contain other groups which may contain even more groups which may contain rectangles or text objects.

Comment: @ArturasM Right, the decorator as I show it only knows how to align the children of the object that it wraps. If group A aligns left, group B aligns right, and group A contains group B, you'd still have to wrap group A and group B to get them to work. Ideally, you won't need to decorate everything, but it depends on the drawing code. I'm glad I could help. Good luck.